# CellTemplate and ContentTemplate not rendering properly in Devextreme ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, devexpress, devextreme

I have a datagrid, where for each item on the table I need to attach one or many documents. When you click the last column button, you should open a popup which then has the file uploader.

I'm trying to create the custom button in my Datagrid, which will open the custom popup that has the FileUploader widget, but the button is not rendering at all.

Instead of the button showing, this is the result.

```
\[%!function(){%\]\ [%DevExpress.aspnet.createComponent("dxButton",{"text":"Attach","onClick":function (e) { attachButtonClick(data) }},arguments\[0\])%\]\[%}("dx-" + new DevExpress.data.Guid())%\]
```

I'm imagining the same will happen even if the popup shows. Just this text which would seem to represent the file uploader.
This is my .chtml code for this part.

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid<myModel>()
        .ID("dataGrid")
        .DataSource(ds => ds.Mvc().Controller("DataGridMaterials")
                                    .LoadAction("Get")
                                    .InsertAction("Insert")
                                    .UpdateAction("Update")
                                    .DeleteAction("Delete")
                                    .Key("ID")
        )
        .Columns(columns => {
            columns.AddFor(m => m.Equipment);
            columns.AddFor(m => m.Client);
            columns.AddFor(m => m.Number);
            columns.AddFor(m => m.Address);
            columns.AddFor(m => m.Phone);
            columns.Add().Width(160).Alignment(HorizontalAlignment.Center).CellTemplate(@<text>
                @Html.DevExtreme().Button().Text("Attach").OnClick("function (e) { attachButtonClick(data) }")
            </text>);
        })

        .OnRowDblClick(@<text>
           function MyHandler(selectedItem) {
                var dataGrid = $("#dataGrid").dxDataGrid("instance");
                var selectedRowsData = dataGrid.getSelectedRowsData();
                var allData = selectedRowsData[0];
                var id = allData.ID;
                console.log(id);

                $('#customPopup').dxPopup('instance').option('visible', true);
           }
        </text>)

        .RowAlternationEnabled(true)
        .Editing(editing => {
            editing.Mode(GridEditMode.Row);
            editing.AllowUpdating(true);
            editing.AllowDeleting(true);
            editing.AllowAdding(true);
        })
        .Selection(s => s.Mode(SelectionMode.Single))
        .RemoteOperations(true)
    )

  @(Html.DevExtreme().Popup().ID("customPopup").Width(660).Height(540).Title("Attachments").Visible(false)
            .ContentTemplate(@<text>

                    @(Html.DevExtreme().FileUploader()
                        .ID("file-uploader")
                        .Name("myFile")
                        .Multiple(true)
                        .Accept("*")
                        .UploadMode(FileUploadMode.UseButtons)
                        .UploadUrl(Url.Action("Upload", "FileUploader"))
                        .OnValueChanged("fileUploader_valueChanged")

                    )
                </text>)
    )
```

I based my solution on this sample app.
[View](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/mvc-datagrid-how-to-create-a-custom-popup-edit-form-and-set-its-content-t591034/blob/17.2.4%2B/CS/DevExtremeMvcApp1/Views/Home/Index.cshtml#L1)

[Custom popup](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/mvc-datagrid-how-to-create-a-custom-popup-edit-form-and-set-its-content-t591034/blob/17.2.4%2B/CS/DevExtremeMvcApp1/Scripts/customPopup/customPopup.js)

Answer (score 1):

It's strange, I follow the sample codes you provide and it can work on my side. I am using `Asp.net core 3.1` and `Devextreme 20.1`:

```
@model Order

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Home</h2>

@(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid<Order>()
        .ID("gridContainer")
        .ShowBorders(true)
        .DataSource(d => d.Mvc().Controller("Orders").LoadAction("Get").Key("OrderID").UpdateAction("Put"))
        .Columns(columns => {
            columns.AddFor(m => m.CustomerName);
            columns.AddFor(m => m.OrderDate);
            columns.AddFor(m => m.ShipCity);
            columns.Add().Width(160).Alignment(HorizontalAlignment.Center).CellTemplate(@<text>
                @Html.DevExtreme().Button().Text("Attach").OnClick("function (e) { attachButtonClick() }")
            </text>);
        })

        .Selection(s => s.Mode(SelectionMode.Single))
        .RemoteOperations(true)
)

@(Html.DevExtreme().Popup().ID("customPopup").Width(660).Height(540).Title("Attachments").Visible(false)
            .ContentTemplate(@<text>

            @(Html.DevExtreme().FileUploader()
                .ID("file-uploader")
                .Name("myFile")
                .Multiple(true)
                .Accept("*")
                .UploadMode(FileUploadMode.UseButtons)
                .UploadUrl(Url.Action("Upload", "FileUploader"))
            )
        </text>)
)

<script>
    function attachButtonClick() {
        $('#customPopup').dxPopup('instance').option('visible', true);
    
    }
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: I made a work around, of course by using the .OnRowDblClick of datagrid, the on the custom pop I have my input of type file. The job is done, but I couldn't find not one post that someone else had/has the same issue. Anyway, thanks for trying and now I know my .chtml is not the issue (or so it seems to me).